# Profiling custom sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, profiling, pipeline

I have created a sklearn pipeline for my project with two component namely, `data_transform` and `model` as shown below.

```
model = Pipeline([
    ('data_transform', XYZ(p1=arg1, p2=arg2)),
    ('model', LogisticRegressionCV(solver='sag', multi_class='multinomial', class_weight='balanced', max_iter=5000))])
```

I call the fit method as `model.fit(X_train, y_train)`. Since, my codetakes lot of time, I wanted to inspect the time taken by each component i.e `data_transform` and `model`. Is there any method from which I could find the time taken?

Answer (score 2):

set `verbose=True` for your `Pipeline` and you will see the time taken by each step of the pipeline, when fit method is applied.

Here's how:

```
model = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('data_transform', XYZ(p1=arg1, p2=arg2)),
    ('model', LogisticRegressionCV(solver='sag', multi_class='multinomial', class_weight='balanced', max_iter=5000))],
                 verbose=True)
```

and when you do:

```
model.fit(your_data)
```

you will see similar output(I am pasting output of my pipeline here)
[image]

Comment: interesting. I will check and mark accept if it works :)